# Computing the degree of a field extension with non-surd roots

Tags: galois-theory

I've been toying with the following idea of a problem after learning some introductory Galois theory:

Consider the polynomial $f = x^4 + x^3 - x^2 + x + 1$, which has real roots $\alpha$ and $1/\alpha$, and complex roots $\beta$ and $\bar{\beta}$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f$. What is $[K:Q]$? (where $Q$ is the rationals)

My idea has been very crude.
Create a tower and then apply tower law: $Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta}) \ / \ Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta) \ / \ Q(\alpha,1/\alpha) \ / \ Q(\alpha) \ / \ Q$.

At first, we have calculate $[Q(\alpha):Q]$. This will be equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $Q$. I know that $m_\alpha = f$, so $[Q(\alpha):Q] = 4$.

Next is to calculate $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha): Q(\alpha)]$, and there is where I have a slight issue.

Firstly, I believe that $1/\alpha \notin Q(\alpha)$ (because $\alpha$ cannot be written in surd form). So $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha): Q(\alpha)]>1$

So we have to find the the minimal polynomial of $1/\alpha$ in $Q(\alpha)$. I know that we can factor $m_\alpha$ in $Q(\alpha)$ to get $m_\alpha = (x-\alpha)f_1 \in Q(\alpha)[x]$. Now, I fully expect that $f_1$ is the minimal polynomial of $1/\alpha$ in $Q(\alpha)$, but I don't know how the show this. So:

- Question 1: Is this the right method to try?
- Question 2: How would I show that $f_1$ is the minimal polynomial here? (I thought about something like the generalised Eisenstein criterion, but then that requires me to calculate prime ideals of $Q(\alpha)$, which sounds very difficult...)

Assuming my vague logic is correct, I would then continue:

We next calculate $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta): Q(\alpha,1/\alpha)]$. By a similar logic to above,  $m_\alpha = (x-\alpha)(x-1/\alpha)f_2 \in Q(\alpha,1/\alpha)[x]$. Knowing that $\beta$ is complex means I know $f_2$ is the minimal polynomial in this case (it can't split into linear factors as $Q(\alpha,1/\alpha)$ is real), and it's easy to see $\deg(f_2)=2$, so $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta): Q(\alpha,1/\alpha)] = 2$.

The final calculation of $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta}): Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta)]$ is, I believe, then trivial.

Finally, that would mean that $[K:Q]=4*3*2*1 = 24$.

Question 3: The second half here works out quite lucky for me. Say I had a degree $6$ polynomial with two real roots and four complex roots (lets call the extra two $\gamma, \bar{\gamma}$). How  best would one proceed to calculate $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta): Q(\alpha,1/\alpha)]$? And $[Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta},\gamma):Q(\alpha,1/\alpha,\beta,\bar{\beta})]$?

I appreciate this seems to be a slightly non-standard problem. Perhaps that's because it is quite difficult and beyond what I've learnt so far? If that's the case, I'd love to know where to learn more?